# Zuul and forwarding url path to another url path

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I using **spring zuul** for managing API_Gateway. But I have the basic problem that can’t forward requests to a specific path. multiple addresses exist in my services that is unchangeable and I will forward from a specific address. I prefer don't use “Zuulfilter” but used that doesn’t useful.

users request:(it's ok)

> Browser Request: gateway.com/api1/user → gateway → apihost.com/api1/user

swagger request:(it's fail)

> Browser Request: gateway.com/api1/swagger → gateway → apihost.com/swagger-ui.html

I using service_discovery (eureka) and My **application.yml** file  configration is:

```
Zuul:
 routes:
   swagger:
     path: /api1/swagger
     service_id: api1
     url: forward:/swagger-ui.html#/
   users:
     path: /api1/user/**
     service_id: api1
     stripPrefix: false
```

But i see at debug mode:

```
2019-01-17 11:28:46.437 DEBUG 77407 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/swagger-ui.html#/api1/swagger]
2019-01-17 11:28:46.437 DEBUG 77407 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /swagger-ui.html#/api1/swagger
2019-01-17 11:28:46.437 DEBUG 77407 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/swagger-ui.html#/api1/swagger]
```

I also added a route filter (Zuulfilter) for directly call address from service but the response is different. That use anyway to use Zuul configuration to forwarding done ( as regards I using service discovery) if not is exist sample code for development servlet filter?

Answer (score 0):

My friend Eureka is for service discovery and Zuul is API gate way.
In the Zuul client add the configuration as shown below in application.yaml.

Try this way: -

```
server:
  port: 9999


eureka:         #tells about the Eureka server details and its refresh time
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/

spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-server


    zuul:
      #Service will be mapped under the /api URI

      routes:    
       service1:
          service-id: id4
          path: /trade/**     
          url: http://localhost:8091
          strip-prefix: false

        service2:

          service-id: id5
          path:  /**
          url: http://localhost:8096
          strip-prefix: false
```

Comment: thanks but I'm using the Eureka (service-discovery) and can't set URL directly.

Comment: Please see the updated answer and we can set the url directly, that is the purpose of Zuul isn't it ?? @Jeus

Comment: I know that but my services IP address is not fixed. and will change URL path from eureka_host_port/api1/swagger to eureka_host_port/swagger-ui.html#/. this sample host and port are equal but the paths (/api1/swgger ≠ /swagger-ui.html#/)  are different.